# An ISO automatically mounts on windows 8

Tags: windows-8, boot, iso-image

When I boot my windows 8 pc, an .iso file is always mounted. I can easily dismount it but this bugs me. It never happened to me with other isos. How do I stop this? I have deamon tools if this can help you. Thanks.

Comment: disable the automounting of the ISO in the Deamon tools options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daemon tool has an option to automunt the ISO at boot. Go into the options and uncheck this option.

[image]